# Wait Until sql query is defined -- NodeJS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

The problem is the `gotxp` variable is undefined when it needs to be used to define `lvl`, which is then sent to the `sendimg()` function.

Is there a way to wait until  `gotxp` is defined?

The `gotxp` variable gets defined by a MySQL query which returns a number.

```
async execute(client, message, args) {
            
        if(!args[0]){

            var gotxp = await readdb(client,message,args);

            let lvl=(gotxp / 100);
            
            console.log('1 lvl ' + lvl + ' gotxp ' + gotxp);//Just a Debug Thing

            
            let username = message.author.username;
            let useravatar = message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' });
            
            sendimg(lvl,username,useravatar,message)
        }

//here is the readdb function
async function readdb(client,message,args){
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
                host: client.dbconfig.host,
                user: client.dbconfig.user,
                password: client.dbconfig.password,
                database: client.dbconfig.database,
                supportBigNumbers: true,
                bigNumberStrings: true
            });
    if(!message.mentions.users.size){
        con.query(`SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE serverid = '${message.guild.id}'`, (err, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                return message.channel.send(`Error - Problema de conexión con la base de datos, prueba más tarde`);
            }
            let nowlvl = 0;
            if(fields.length >= 1){
                let id = message.author.id;
                let gotfields = search(fields,id)
                console.log(gotfields)
                if(typeof gotfields != 'undefined') {
                    
                    nowlvl = gotfields.xp;
                    console.log('1 nowlvl ' + nowlvl);
                }
                else{
                    
                    nowlvl = 0;
                    console.log('2 nowlvl ' + nowlvl);
                }
            }
            setTimeout(function() { con.end() }, 100)
            return nowlvl;
        });
    }
    else{
        con.query(`SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE serverid = '${message.guild.id}'`, (err, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                return message.channel.send(`Error - Problema de conexión con la base de datos, prueba más tarde`);
            }
            let nowlvl = 0
            if(fields.length >= 1){
                var id = message.mentions.users.map(user => {
                    return `${user.id}`;
                });
                let gotfields = search(fields,id)
                
                if(typeof gotfields != 'undefined') {
                    nowlvl = gotfields.xp;
                    console.log('3 nowlvl ' + nowlvl);
                }
                else{
                    nowlvl = 0;
                    console.log('4 nowlvl ' + nowlvl);
                }
            }
            setTimeout(function() { con.end() }, 100)
            return nowlvl;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `readdb`? Is that an async function?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros yes it is

Comment: If it returns a promise and you use await, it will wait till it's resolved. Could you update your post and add your code for `readdb`?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros here it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await` need to accept a `promise`, so we need to add `promise` to `readdb`:

```
function readdb(client, message, args) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: client.dbconfig.host,
      user: client.dbconfig.user,
      password: client.dbconfig.password,
      database: client.dbconfig.database,
      supportBigNumbers: true,
      bigNumberStrings: true
    });
    if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
      con.query(
        `SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE serverid = '${message.guild.id}'`,
        (err, fields) => {
          if (err) {
            return message.channel.send(
              `Error - Problema de conexión con la base de datos, prueba más tarde`
            );
          }
          let nowlvl = 0;
          if (fields.length >= 1) {
            let id = message.author.id;
            let gotfields = search(fields, id);
            console.log(gotfields);
            if (typeof gotfields != "undefined") {
              nowlvl = gotfields.xp;
              console.log("1 nowlvl " + nowlvl);
            } else {
              nowlvl = 0;
              console.log("2 nowlvl " + nowlvl);
            }
          }
          setTimeout(function () {
            con.end();
          }, 100);
          resolve(nowlvl);
        }
      );
    } else {
      con.query(
        `SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE serverid = '${message.guild.id}'`,
        (err, fields) => {
          if (err) {
            return message.channel.send(
              `Error - Problema de conexión con la base de datos, prueba más tarde`
            );
          }
          let nowlvl = 0;
          if (fields.length >= 1) {
            var id = message.mentions.users.map((user) => {
              return `${user.id}`;
            });
            let gotfields = search(fields, id);

            if (typeof gotfields != "undefined") {
              nowlvl = gotfields.xp;
              console.log("3 nowlvl " + nowlvl);
            } else {
              nowlvl = 0;
              console.log("4 nowlvl " + nowlvl);
            }
          }
          setTimeout(function () {
            con.end();
          }, 100);
          resolve(nowlvl);
        }
      );
    }
  });
}
```